# ARP Ping to one linux machine throwing No address associated with name

Tags: linux, rhel, arp

We are trying to use ARP (arping) to reach one linux machine, it throws following error:

```
exec failed: 1: \S
Kernel \r on an \m
                                !!!WARNING!!!
############################################################################
ACCESS TO THIS SYSTEM IS STRICTLY RESTRICTED TO AUTHORIZED PERSONS ONLY
UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS TO THIS SYSTEM IS NOT ALLOWED AND EVERY ACTIVITY IS MONITORED ON THIS
                                  SYSTEM.
###########################################################################################
addr: error fetching interface information: Device not found
dev: No address associated with name
```

Can you please help me with this? Should we enable something on the machine?

Below is the command I am using in perl script:

```
/apps/gateway/sbin/arping -q -c 3 -A -I $dev $2 2 >/dev/null
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please update the command you are trying to use.

Comment: Updated command @SantoshGarole

Comment: It is taking `dev` as hostname please pass it correctly so that it will ping to correct device name

Comment: Why its throwing the permission error as above? Its working on test bed, but this error seen in production? is it internet issue or permission?                                                                                                    If its taking dev, then it should throw following error right, i just command in local system :                                                                                                                                           arping -c 3 -I dev 10.10.221.125
arping: Device dev not available.